# Create short bibliography with bibtexkeys from aux files (biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex, auxiliary-files

I have a draft version of a large latex document with a long bibliography (>30 pages long).
It has been created with `biblatex` and has about 330 entries.

I'm editing a printout of the draft version and 
I'd like to create 
 a short version of the bibliography to have a more compact copy
which contains

- the bibtexkey for each entry
- the number (like [3])
- and the most important data of the entry (title, year, authors, where published, pages) - no URLs

Is there an easy way to do that in a separate document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add entry keys to the bibliography, you can redefine `\begentry`. Omitting data from the bibliography can be done using the `\clearfield`, `\clearlist` and `\clearname` commands, which can be executed using the `\AtEveryBibitem` hook.

None of these commands affect the bibliographic data, so a document with a "short" version of the bibliography can be generated without having to re-run `biber`/`bibtex`. The code below provides an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newtoggle{draftbib}

% Comment this line for full bibliography
\toggletrue{draftbib}

\iftoggle{draftbib}
  {\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
     \printtext{\mkbibbold{\thefield{entrykey}}}\addcolon\addspace}
   \AtEveryBibitem{%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \clearfield{subtitle}%
     \clearfield{booktitle}%
     \clearfield{booksubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{url}%
     \clearfield{doi}}}
  {}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bertram,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
@Book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  date = {1994}}
@InBook{nietzsche,
  author = {Nietzsche, Friedrich},
  bookauthor = {Nietzsche, Friedrich},
  editor = {Colli, Giorgio and Montinari, Mazzino},
  title = {Unzeitgem{\"a}sse Betrachtungen. Zweites St{\"u}ck},
  subtitle = {Vom Nutzen und Nachtheil der Historie f{\"u}r das Leben},
  booktitle = {Die Geburt der Trag{\"o}die. Unzeitgem{\"a}{\ss}e Betrachtungen I--IV. Nachgelassene Schriften 1870--1973},
  maintitle = {S{\"a}mtliche Werke},
  mainsubtitle = {Kritische Studienausgabe},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {Deutscher Taschenbuch-Verlag and Walter de Gruyter},
  location = {M{\"u}nchen and Berlin and New York},
  date = {1988},
  pages = {243--334}}
@Online{ctan,
  title = {CTAN},
  subtitle = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  date = {2006},
  url = {http://www.ctan.org}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much - I was not successful at first, maybe because of forbidden characters in the bib files. I'm sorry, could you please add to your answer what I have to do to adapt the example to my case? Do I have to `\addbibresource` the 3 bib files which I use in my main.tex document? Do I have to add information about my `main.tex` document? Do I have to run bibtex on the file or only `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Martin From the code above, copy and paste lines 5-22 into the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) of `main.tex`. Then run `pdflatex main`. Your new `pdf` document will have a short version of the bibliography. To revert back to the long bibliography, comment out `\toggletrue{draftbib}` and run `pdflatex main` again. Additional fields can be suppressed in the short bibliography by adding more `\clearfield`, `\clearname` and `\clearlist` commands within `\AtEveryBibitem`.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Would it be possible to create the new, short bibliography in a separate pdf document with nothing else in it (and without changing the original tex file or pdf)?

Comment: @Martin I think so. Make a copy of the file `main.bbl` and call it, say, `shortbib.bbl`. Create a new file `shortbib.tex` containing code similar to the example above, but delete lines 24-61. Replace these with `\addbibresource` commands referring to your actual `bib` files. Then run `pdflatex shortbib`.